# Place an image for submit button in Zend form

Tags: image, zend-framework, button

I have a form made by Zend Framework that needs a submit button. I want to place an image instead of the default button. The code I have is this:

```
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit( 'submit');
```

However, I can not add an image for the submit button here. If I create the form with the following code, it works:

```
$this->addElement('image', 'submit', array(
        'ignore'   => true,
        'label'=>'Submit',
        'src' => ('/media/css/image/submit.png'),
         ));
```

How can I add image instead of the default submit button in the first approach of form creation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Image('submit', array(
    'ignore' => true,
    'label'  => 'Submit',
    'src'    => '/media/css/image/submit.png'
));
```