# Styling a submit button using zend form

Tags: php, image, zend-framework, button

Currently my button is used in a Zend form, I can work out how to add tags etc. but nothing I am doing at the minute with either the HTML or the CSS is giving it any results.

My code for the button is below:

```
class Application_Form_Newsletter extends Zend_Form
{
    public $processed = false;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->addElement(
            'text', 'email', array(
                'label' => '',
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(
                array('StringLength', false, array('max'=>150)),
                'EmailAddress',
                ),
            )
        );

        $this->addElement('submit', 'go', array(

            'id'=>'btnNewsletter',
            'type'=>'image',            
          ));
    }
}
```

The style sheet code is a follows:

```
#btnNewsletter{ background-image: url('../img/home-search-background-btn.png');}
```

I've managed to get the image to display but it is always hidden behind the actual button itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#btnNewsletter {
    background-image: url('../img/home-search-background-btn.png');
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    text-indent: -1000px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Also add width and height values to match the dimensions of your button. The `text-indent` directive shifts the button text out of view so that the image is the only thing you see.

Alternatively you could use an image submit, see this question for an example: [Place an image for submit button in Zend form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652152/place-an-image-for-submit-button-in-zend-form)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure it out exactly like this. The 'border' property is key, thats what made it stop looking like a gray button.